# CSS margin won't work in stylesheet but in code

Tags: css, margin

I have a style that works fine in "code":

```
<img class="minbild" style="margin-right: 22px; float: left;" src="/images/Etiketter/AmarilloSingleHopEtikett.jpg" alt="AmarilloSingleHopEtikett" width="300" height="300" />
```

This will set the margin-right to 22 px. When I move it to the "minbild" class it stops working...

```
.minbild {
margin-right:62px;

box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #555, 0px 0px 0px 10px #eee, 0px 0px 0px 11px #555, 3px 3px  5px 11px #555;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #555, 0px 0px 0px 10px #eee, 0px 0px 0px 11px #555, 3px 3px 5px 11px #555;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #555, 0px 0px 0px 10px #eee, 0px 0px 0px 11px #555, 3px 3px 5px 11px #555;
}
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?  I use the same css-file for my jceditor and it shows the margin fine! I have tried Chrome and IE9.

Comment: You `class` version does not have the float applied...could that be it?

Comment: Do you have any other CSS rules that come after the one you show above that might be changing the margin?

Comment: Inline styles have a higher precedence than stylesheets, perhaps there's another rule that overrides the declaration for `.minibild`, can we see the rest of your stylesheet?

Comment: Are you keeping the `margin` style inline when the class is applied?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inline css, it should fix the problem:

```
<img class="minbild" src="/images/Etiketter/AmarilloSingleHopEtikett.jpg" alt="AmarilloSingleHopEtikett" width="300" height="300" />
```

Inline CSS was taking priority over external css.